# ASP.NET/IIS HttpErrors and access denied response

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a site where only authorizated users can access.

I also have a custom error page if a **401.2** is raised.

I configured `web.config` in the following way:

```
  <system.webServer>             
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1"
             path="ERRORS\unauthorized.html"
             responseMode="File">
      </error>
    </httpErrors>    
  </system.webServer>
```

However when I try access to my site the following happen:

1. http://localhost --> the `ERRORS\unauthorized.html` is showed;
2. http://localhost/index.html --> the `ERRORS\unauthorized.html` **is not** showed and I can access the page!

I also noticed two things:

1. if I change the page to `index.aspx` the `ERRORS\unauthorized.html` is showed;
2. if I use a different `statusCode`, i.e., 404 the HTML page is showed.

so what am I not understanding? Where is my mistake?

**P.S.
I'm using IIS 10 and .NET 4.7**

Comment: What authentication method are you using now?

Comment: windows authentication

Answer (score 0):

What authentication are you using? 
Assuming you are using Anonymous authentication at the IIS level and some kind of authentication in asp.net or system.web layer, the asp.net pipeline doesn't come into picture when you access the static files as they are handled by the static file handler. SO the authorization is not coming into picture. ALso try to configure the app pool to run in integrated mode and try, because integrated mode combines iis and asp.net pipeline, if youa are running in classic it won't

ALso to add another note on the line, 401.2 is a status responded back by the server that there is no user info being passed and client has to login, this doesn't necessarily have to deal with authorization and it is a way of authentication how servers work.

Comment: I'm using windows authentication

Comment: Did you check by changing the app pool mode from classic to integrated and also, collect failed request tracing and check the difference in flow for the requests when you access a aspx page and an html page which should give you more idea